# How I can keep variable in controller/action after form has been invalid (population)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Got action with one waiting for parameter , and to run this action I need always one param. But also in this action I doing validation for other form and after this my first variable always disappears. 
How I can keep this `$var` after isValid?

```
public function myAction(){  
   if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() || $this->getRequest()->getParam('number')){  
     //this is where got my number
     $number = $this->getRequest()->getParam ('number');
     //and use to display site.        
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
      if($commentForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
         //if I get Valid data I do upload or etc.
      } else {
             //but if form is inValid won't display everything one more time.
             //but **$number is now Null**.  
             $this->view->data = $tUser->getCommentAndUserByTelephone($number);
             $this->view->commentForm = $commentForm;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How I can keep this `$number` without repost?

Comment: There isn't any reason that the code you've posted wouldn't work. Are you sure the form submits to the correct URL (with the number parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing it with sessions.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

```
$_SESSION['numbers'];
```

Comment: I always can repost, but any different idea?

Answer (score 0):

Pass that number to view `$this->view->number = $number;` and resend it instead of a new number. Simple!